# Custom Keys to Android default keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

I am trying to add some custom keys to the soft keyboard (like a new row of specialized keys on top of the existing keyboard)
I assume the only way would be to get a reference to that keyboard. I know it's possible to get the size of the keyboard (using ViewTreeObserver), but I can't find a way to get the actual keyboard object.
Also, I can add a custom keyboard, but there are a few things that makes everything a bit more complicated, like switching from alphanumeric to special characters and also Shift behaviour. So that's why I'd prefer adding the keys to the existing keyboard, if possible.
Can anyone confirm that's possible? Or that it's not possible?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is a bit complicated and long way but, you can create your own Keyboard with using Android AOSP Latin IME library from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/)

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. You would have to create a whole new keyboard.

Comment: Thanks, Aytek, Richard. It sounds like I need to use a keyboard made from scratch. I'll look into the Latin Keyboard, it seems very useful.